# How to post JSON in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, request

My controller and model classes look like below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/apkinfo")
public class ApkInfoController {


  public @ResponseBody String registerApk(@RequestBody ApkInfoReq req){
         //Do something
  }
}

public class ApkInfo implements Serializable {

     private String deviceId;
     private List<ApkInfo> apkinfo;

     //gettters and setters
}

public class ApkInfo  implements Serializable {

     private String appName;
     private String packageName;
     private String version;
     private Date installDate;
}
```

Then I tried to post the data to server using jQuery Ajax.

```
var param = {
   deviceId: '1234',
   apkinfo: [
      {appName:'a', packageName:'a.a', version: '1', installDate:"2013-05-03 10:00:00"},
      {appName:'b', packageName:'a.b', version: '2', installDate:"2013-05-03 10:00:00"} 
   ]
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'to_my_server_url',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: param,
    error: function(){},
    success: function(data){
        //do something
    } 
})
```

But I am getting an error 'Unspported MediaType'. I have Jackson Mapping setting in my applicationContext.xml and @ResponseBody of other mothods work fine.

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package: "xx.xx.xxxxx.xx";
<contex:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jacksonMappingConverter"    class="org.springframework.htttp.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
              <ref bean ="jacksonMappingConverter" />
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

How can I POST the JOSN data? Thanks.

EDIT:

Before sending request I converted it to JSON Object:

$.ajax({
   ...
   data: JSON.stringify(param)
   ...
});

And I have Jackson library in my pom.xml and no issue with @ResponseBody.

I missed installDate field.

Comment: I fixed the problem now. Problem was the apkinfo field alpahbet case in the ApkInfoReq class. The setter for the field public void setApkInfo(List<ApkInfo> apkInfo) So, I think Jackson mapper tried to use apkInfo as the key name but my field was 'apkinfo', all lowercase. I changed the case and then now it works. Thanks anyway, guys.

Answer (score 0):

do you have jackson jar inside your classpath? You can also add @RequestMapping(value="/mapping", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) on your method handler see this sample- [MappingController](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/mapping/MappingController.java)

Comment: I think so. In my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehau.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

```
var param = { deviceId: '1234', ...
$.ajax({ ... data: param, ...
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): "**data** ... It is converted to a **query string**, if not already a string.

So if you don't convert `param` to a `JSON` string somewhere else in the code then you are not sending `JSON` to the server. You can do that with

```
data: JSON.stringify(param)
```

Comment: Thanks for the point. I set contentType: applicatoin/json and I could received the request as JSON handling like this:

$.ajax({
    url: 'my_url',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : { param : {deviceId: '1234', apkinfo:[{},{}]}},
    
});


public @ResponseBody String registerApk(@RequestBody String param){
         //Do something
}

But I could not convert the JSON as ApkInfoReq object.

Anyway, I will try it as you said.

Comment: I added installDate field of the class, which was missing and headers="Content-Type=application/json" in the controller class. Now I am getting 'Bad request' error.

Comment: @shungun In your JavaScript code `installDate` is a `String` and it's not a standard format. I suggest using a `Date` object instead.